# RoR will_paginate No route matches error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

**offers_controller.rb file**

```
def store_locator
  city_name = params[:city]
  @flag = true
  per_page = 5
  if !city_name.blank?
    store = StoreCity.find_by_city(city_name.downcase)
  end
  if !store.nil?
    @storelist= StoreAddress.where(:city_id=>store.id)
    @flag = false
  else 
  @storelist= StoreAddress.order(:store_name).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => per_page)
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

store_locator.html.erb pops up following error

> No route matches {:action=>"store_locator", :controller=>"spree/offers", :escape=>nil, :page=>2}** at
>
> ```
> <%=will_paginate @storelist ,:params => { :escape => nil }, :class => 'store_paging'%>
> ```

code snippet:

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="loadicon"></div>
  <%if @flag%>
    <%=will_paginate @storelist ,:params => { :escape => nil }, :class => 'store_paging'%> 
  <%end%>
<div id="storediv" style="background-color:#efefef;">
```

routes.rb has proper namespacing

```
get '/store_locator' => 'offers#store_locator'
```

will_paginate version 3.1.5
RoR version 4.2.3

Answer (score 0):

check routes using command:

```
rake routes
```

which list all routes and check /store_locator is call which controller and action.

Comment: also inspect element of view and check the path which is mentioned in html on pagination.

Comment: ` store_locator GET          /store_locator(.:format)                                   offers#store_locator` above is the output of rake routes.

Comment: Your error ie
No route matches {:action=>"store_locator", :controller=>"spree/offers", :escape=>nil, :page=>2}** at

shows that request find your controller ie offers controler in spree folder.

Try to put your offers controller under spree ie

app -> controllers -> spree -> offers controller

Comment: The offers_controller is under app->contollers->spree folder.

Comment: try to change post instead of get in routes.rb

Comment: I am able to hit the store_locator method in offers_controller.  `<div class="col-md-12" id="loadicon"></div>  <%if @flag%>  <%=will_paginate @storelist ,:params => { :escape => nil }, :class => 'store_paging'%>  <%end%>  <div id="storediv" style="background-color:#efefef;">`  `<%=will_paginate @storelist ,:params => { :escape => nil }, :class => 'store_paging'%>` throws the mentioned error